# Move div up and down dynamically by clicking content menu buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a move up and move down button in my context menu for multiple div drop.  I want to move my div down after clicking move down, but I am unable to do so.

Below is the code that I am currently using.

```
$(".propertyClass").live('click', function(event) {
    tempId = this.parentElement.parentElement.attributes[0].nodeValue;
    $.contextMenu({

        selector : '.propertyClass',
        trigger : 'left',
        callback : function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            if (!(key == ""))
                // alert(key);
                optionObject[key](event);
            //window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
        },
        items : {
            "moveUp" : {
                name : "Move Up",
                icon : "MoveUp"
            },
            "moveDown" : {
                name : "Move Down",
                icon : "MoveDown"
            },
            "Duplicate" : {
                name : "Duplicate",
                icon : "duplicate"
            },

            "Delete" : {
                name : "Delete",
                icon : "delete"
            },

            "sep1" : "---------",
            "showProperties" : {
                name : "Properties",
                icon : "properties"
            }
        }
    });
});

var optionObject = {

    "moveUp" : function() {
        alert("1");
    },
    "moveDown" : function(event) {
        for ( l = 0; l < workspace.length; l++) {
            //console.log(event.pageX);
            // event.pageX="220px";
            // event.pageY="60px";
        }
    },
    "Duplicate" : function(event) {
        var temp = tempId.split("_");
        switch(temp[0]) {
            case "head":
                createHead(workspace);

                break;
            case "txtBox":
                createTextbox(workspace);
                break;
            case "mob":
                createMobno(workspace);
                break;
            case "txtArea":
                createTextArea(workspace);
                break;
            case "fname":
                createfullName(workspace);
                break;

        }
    },
    "showProperties" : function() {
        $("#propertyDialog").dialog({
            height : 300,
            color : "grey",
            width : 600,
            title : "Properties",
            close : function(event, ui) {
                $("#propertyDialog").html("");
            }
        });

        $("#propertyDialog").html("<div id='propDialogDiv1'>General Settings : <table border='1px solid' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4'><tr><td><div id='propDialogDiv2'>Text</div></td><td><div id='propDialogDiv3'> <input id='propDialogDiv2' type='text'  onClick='this.contentEditable=true;' value='hii'></div></td></tr><td></td><tr></tr><tr><td id='propDialogDiv2'>Field Details</td></tr><tr><td id='propDialogDiv2'>ID:</td><td>" + tempId + "</td></table></div>");

    },
    "Delete" : function(event) {
        for (var k = 0; k < workspace.length; k++) {
            if (tempId == workspace[k].main.id) {
                $(workspace[k].main).remove();
                workspace.splice(k, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean : change their places (rotation) or the position on the screen?

Comment: YES interchanging the closest one

Comment: Could you post your HTML code also? Or something corresponding to your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to move a div in a context menu down (and replace it with the one below it) when the down arrow is clicked.

To do this just have your on click event use insertBefore and have all the divs the are in the menu be children of a parent menu div.

eg: https://mod.it/ItyD_VPb (must view in chrome but code is cross browser, look at main.js file).

The example above will put whichever of the 2 divs is on the bottom on the top when clicked.